# How can I extract U.S. DoD contract information to use in statistical analysis?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to scrape and analyze the contracts the defense department gets, correlating it with other economic data I've already got.  It's all publicly available on [Defense.gov](http://www.defense.gov/contracts/default.aspx).

However, they don't list it in a table, rather the relevant information (Contractor, Date, Name, Contract ID, etc) are written in paragraph form.  I've been trying to get the data into a CSV so I can run it through R.

Normally I'd just extract based on the tags around the data, but can anyone recommend a simpler way of getting at this data?  I've already pulled the data using wget, but I'm just trying to extract it.

This is an [example of a typical paragraph](http://www.defense.gov/Contracts/Contract.aspx?ContractID=4673):

> Booz Allen Hamilton, Inc., Herndon, Va., is being awarded a $9,450,189 cost-plus-fixed-fee, indefinite-delivery, requirements contract for research and development in order to complete/deliver the assessment of army warfighting challenges and integrated learning plans, the experiment final reports, and experiment-to-action plans.  The U.S. Army will use these reports to develop and revise Army concepts and contribute to other services and joint concepts; make recommendations for the development of Army and joint capabilities development scenarios; research current and future warfare through experimentation; and build models and simulations to test new warfighting ideas.  ESG/PKS DTIC, Offut Air Force Base, Neb., is the contracting activity (SP0700-03-D-1380, Delivery Order: 0452).

I started with a Perl script, but the extraction isn't working out so well.  I'm curious if anyone's built a script that's more dynamic that I can build off of rather then rebuilding from scratch.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;


# Create a new workbook called simple.xls and add a worksheet.
my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('Dec4_min.xls');
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
our $row = 0;


@files = <~/Def_Contracts/*.*>;

foreach $HTML (@files) {                # open each file in folder  #$HTML = "contract.html";
    open (HTML) or die "Can't open the file!";
    @fullpage = <HTML>;
    print "fullpage array size = ", @fullpage. "\n";

my @cleaned;                        # this is a simplified array we will create

foreach $curr (@fullpage){              #this for each loop cuts array elements without dollar signs

# [0-9]+?\/[0-9]+?\/[0-9]{3}

        if($curr =~ m/content="([0-9]+?\/[0-9]+?\/[0-9]{4})/) {     #get date - looking for this: content="8/29/1995"
        print $1;
#           if ($currnt =~ m/([0-9]+,.[0-9]{4}/){   #  extract date dd,(space)dddd  
        our $date = $1;
        }

                            # CLEAN UP
    while(substr($curr,0,1) =~ m/[^\w]/){       # while not a word char   
            substr($curr,0,1)='';                 #cut that char
    }   
    if($curr =~ m/\$[0-9]/) {           # only use if has $number.


#######################  Now we've got what we need, output relevant parts into excel.


        my $firstcom = index($curr, ',');
        $name = substr($curr,0,$firstcom); 
    #   print "Name:", $name. "\n";
        $worksheet->write($row,0,$name);        # print the name in the first col

        $worksheet->write($row,1,$date);            # print the date in the 2nd col

        if($curr =~ m/\$([0-9,]*)/) {           # finds the cost PROBLEM: there may be more than one
    #   print "Cost:", $1. "\n";
        $worksheet->write($row,2,$1);
        }

        if($curr =~ m/([A-Za-z0-9][A-Z0-9]{4}[A-Z0-9]?\-[0-9]+\-[A-Z]\-[A-Z0-9]{4})/) {     # print ref # in 3rd col
    #   print "Cost:", $1. "\n";
        $worksheet->write($row,3,$1);               # ref takes form (letter ...-...-...number)
        }
                                            # 2nd attempt to get ref #
        if($curr =~ m/\((.*\-.*\-.*)\)/){   # print ref # in 4rd col
    #   print "Cost:", $1. "\n";
        $worksheet->write($row,4,$1);               # ref takes form (letter ...-...-...number)
        }

        $worksheet->write($row,5,$curr);        # print full record (for verification!)

        $row ++;    
    }                           # close for if has a number statement
}                               # close foreach line of HTML Page

#print "cleaned array size = ", @cleaned. "\n";



print "The end.\n";
close (HTML);

}               # End of foreach file
```

Comment: Looks like a good start, but that's a very specific input you're parsing. What kind of problems are you seeing?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, very incomplete, but then, normally it takes a significant amount of cash to convince me to deal with this kind of mess (`VIEWSTATE`, really?):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;
use Regexp::Common qw( number );

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new('contract.html');
my %contracts;

while (my $tag = $parser->get_tag('p')) {
    if (defined( my $align = $tag->get_attr('align')) ) {
        my $text = get_text_in_p($parser);
        next unless defined $text;

        if (lc($text) eq 'contracts') {
            process_contracts($parser, \%contracts);
        }
    }
}

use YAML;
print Dump \%contracts;

sub process_contracts {
    my ($parser, $contracts) = @_;

    my $current_dept = '';

    while (my $tag = $parser->get_tag('p')) {
        my $text = get_text_in_p($parser);
        next unless defined $text;

        if (defined $tag->get_attr('align')) {
            $current_dept = $text;
            next;
        }

        my ($company)  = ($text =~ /^(.+?), (?:is|was)/);

        my ($amount)   = ($text =~ m{
                (
                    \$
                    $RE{num}{int}{-base => 10}{-sep => ','}
                )
            }x
        );

        my ($contract) = ($text =~ m{
                (
                    [A-Z0-9]{6}
                    [A-Z0-9/-]+
                )
            }x
        );

        push @{ $contracts->{$current_dept} }, {
            company  => $company,
            amount   => $amount,
            contract => $contract,
            # text     => $text,
        };
    }
}

sub get_text_in_p {
    my ($parser) = @_;
    my $text = $parser->get_text('/p');
    return unless defined $text;

    $text =~ s/^[^A-Z]+//;
    $text =~ s/\s+\z//;

    return $text;
}
```

Output for [No. 1001-11](http://www.defense.gov/contracts/contract.aspx?contractid=4678):

```
---
DEFENSE LOGISTICS AGENCY:
  - amount: '$49,418,113'
    company: 'Physio-Control, Inc., Redmond, Wash.'
    contract: SPM200-07-D-8261/P00005
  - amount: '$43,246,524'
    company: 'Johnson & Johnson Healthcare Systems, on behalf of Ortho-McNell-Janssen Pharmaceuticals, Inc., Piscataway, N.J.'
    contract: SPM2D0-12-D-0001
  - amount: '$15,240,054'
    company: 'Patterson Dental Supply, Inc., Minn.'
    contract: SPM2DE-10-D-7447/P00005
NAVY:
  - amount: '$60,360,995'
    company: 'Raytheon Co., Integrated Defense Systems, San Diego, Calif.'
    contract: N00024-11-C-2404
  - amount: '$33,693,891'
    company: 'Wyle Laboratories, Inc., Huntsville, Ala.'
    contract: N00421-03-D-0015
  - amount: '$30,071,729'
    company: 'Deloitte Consulting, L.L.P., Lexington Park, Md.'
    contract: N00421-03-D-0014
  - amount: '$22,151,900'
    company: 'Raytheon Co., Tucson, Ariz.'
    contract: N00024-08-C-5401
  - amount: '$18,508,325'
    company: 'Canadian Commercial Corp., General Dynamics Land Systems - Canada, Ontario, Canada'
    contract: M67854-07-D-5028
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at a few entries, I suspect these paragraphs are entered manually using a bunch of boilerplate templates.  (The different branches / agencies seem to have their own formats; for example, the Air Force and the Navy write "is being awarded", while the Army and the DLA use "was awarded", and [some other agencies have their own peculiar variants](http://www.defense.gov/contracts/contract.aspx?contractid=4664).)

Thus, it seems unlikely that you can write code to parse *all* the entries reliably.  The best you can do is probably to write a bunch of regexps to parse most (say, 99% or so) of them, and flag the rest for manual processing.

I'm too tired to write a more detailed answer right now, but I'd suggest starting with something like this:

```perl
my (@records, @rejects);
foreach (split /\n\s*\n/, $text) {  # split page into paragraphs
    s#\s+# #g; s#^ ##; s# $##;      # normalize whitespace
    my (%data, @m);

    if (@m = /^(.*), (?:is being|was) awarded a \$([0-9,]+) (.*) contract to (.*)\. (.*), is the contracting activity(?: \(([A-Z]{2}\d{4}-\d\d-[A-Z]-\d{4})(?:, Delivery Order: (\d+))?\))?\.$/) {
        @data{qw(company amount contract_type purpose activity contract_id delivery_order)} = @m;
    }
    elsif (@m = /^...$/) {
        @data{qw(...)} = @m;
    }
    # ...
    else {
        push @rejects, $_;
        next;
    }
    push @records, \%data;
}
```

Then go through the entries being rejected, add new regexps (or adjust existing ones) to handle the most common types among them, and repeat.  Also remember to check the parsed output to see if the regexps are working correctly, of course.